# How to find day difference between a date with `YYYY-MM-DD` format and today's date in Unix shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, date

I have a date say `2015-12-30`. I want to find the day difference between this day and today's date.

Currently I am doing this

```
dest_date="2015-12-30"
now=`date +%Y-%m-%d`

echo "( `date -d $dest_date +%s` - `date -d $now +%s`) / (24*3600)" | bc -l
```

But this is giving error as

```
date: invalid date `+%s'
(standard_in) 1: parse error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this:

```
dest_date="2015-12-30"
diff=$(( ($(date '+%s' -d "$dest_date") - $(date '+%s')) / 86400 ))

echo $diff
14
```